# Bigquery: substring by dropping after a certain position

Tags: google-bigquery

This is quite odd, but getting a substring of a string column using `LEFT()` or `SUBSTR()` by dropping after a certain position seems to be impossible.

Using the example data from BQ [docs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/string_functions#substr):

```
WITH items AS
  (SELECT 'apple' as item
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'banana' as item
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'orange' as item)


desired output:

+---------+
| example |
+---------+
| app     |
| bana    |
| oran    |
+---------+
```

Here, I would get a substring of each row by dropping 2 characters from the right. Funnily enough, there doesn't seem to be an easy, base BQ function to retrieve this, as `LEFT()` or `SUBSTRING()` does not take a negative position entry.

I am aware that for certain strings, `REGEXP_SUBSTR` can be used, but I want to find a feasible solution to getting a substring based on a position instead of filtering characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> there doesn't seem to be an easy, base BQ function to retrieve this

I think you can try this

```sql
WITH items AS (
  SELECT 'apple' as item
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'banana' as item
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'orange' as item
)
SELECT SUBSTR(item , 1, LENGTH(item) - 2) example FROM items;

--Query results
+---------+
| example |
+---------+
| app     |
| bana    |
| oran    |
+---------+
```

Doesn't look good but below is possible as well.

```sql
SELECT REVERSE(SUBSTR(REVERSE(item) , 3)) example  FROM items;
```

- `3` will discard 1st and 2nd characters from the reversed string which means last 2 characters of the original string.